# SQLiteDataReader error, near "table": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have simple SQLite db table in my C# project
[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfyWJ.png)

Here is the code which I using to retrieve data from DB:

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnection;
dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=./new.db;");
dbConnection.Open();
if (dbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
     richTextBox3.Text = "Conn";
string sqlcommand = "SELECT age FROM table WHERE index=1";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlcommand, dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
if(result.HasRows)
{
      while (result.Read())
      {
           richTextBox1.Text = result.GetInt32(0) + " "+ result.GetString(1) + " " + result.GetInt32(2);
       }
 }
```

Maybe the while loop is incorrect but my problem is the syntax error near the table.

Comment: table is a keyword you have to use your table name (other than table word) inplace of table word..

Comment: The loop will not work also. In the loop you are requesting 3 fields at index 0,1,2 but your select has only one field. This will be available at index 0. Asking for index 1 and 2 will result in an IndexOutOfRange exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rohit mentioned `table` is a keyword in SQLite but if you still want to use it you can change you query as below:
by surrounding your table name by `[table]`

```
string sqlcommand = "SELECT age FROM [table] WHERE index=1";
```

It also works in `SQLSERVER`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `` between table because table is reserved word. You can check all reserved words on [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql)

```
string sqlcommand = "SELECT `age` FROM `table` WHERE `index`='1'";
```